# Computing the derivative of $J(u) = \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^p \ dx$ - What fact was used in this passage of the proof?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, calculus-of-variations

My question is:

> What is the statement of this "Lagrange Theorem" used in the last step below?

Let $\Omega \subset \Bbb{R}^N$ be an open set, $N \geq 3$. For $p \in (1, \infty)$ define a functional $J: W_0^{1, p} (\Omega) \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ by
$$
J(u) = \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^p \ dx.
$$

We want to show that $J$ is differentiable and that 
$$
J'(u)v = p \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^{p - 2} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \ dx, \quad v \in W_0^{1, p} (\Omega)
$$

The book I am reading (Badiale and Serra, *Semilinear Elliptic Equations for Beginners*) proceeds as follows:

Let $\varphi: \Bbb{R}^N \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ defined by $\varphi(x) = |x|^p$. It is a $C^1$ function with $\nabla \varphi (x) = p|x|^{p - 2}x$, so for all $x, y \in \Bbb{R}^N$ we have that 
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\varphi(x + ty) - \varphi(x)}{t} = p |x|^{p - 2}x \cdot y
$$
(it is just the directional derivative). As a consequence, 
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{|\nabla u(x) + t \nabla v(x)|^p - |\nabla u (x)|^p}{t} = p |\nabla u(x)|^{p - 2}\nabla u(x) \cdot \nabla v (x) \quad \text{ a.e. in } \Omega.
$$
Now, and here lies my doubt, the book argues that by Lagrange's Theorem there exists $\theta \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $|\theta| \leq |t|$ and 
$$
\left| \frac{|\nabla u+ t \nabla v|^p - |\nabla u|^p}{t} \right| \leq p \left||\nabla u + \theta \nabla v|^{p - 2} (\nabla u + \theta \nabla v) \cdot \nabla v\right|.
$$

Any references or hints will be the most appreciated.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$ f(t)=|\nabla u+ t \nabla v|^p$$
and then
$$ f(t)=((\nabla u+ t \nabla v)\cdot(\nabla u+ t \nabla v))^{\frac p2}=(|\nabla u|^2+2t\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+t^2|\nabla v|^2)^{\frac p2}. $$
Noting that
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(t)&=&\frac p2 (|\nabla u|^2+2t\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+t^2|\nabla v|^2)^{\frac p2-1}(2\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+2t|\nabla v|^2) \\
&=&p||\nabla u+ t \nabla v|^{p-2}(\nabla u+t\nabla v)\cdot \nabla v.
\end{eqnarray*}
By the Mean Value Theorem, there is $\theta$ such that
$$ f(t)-f(0)=tf'(\theta),|\theta|<|t| $$
or
$$
\frac{|\nabla u+ t \nabla v|^p - |\nabla u|^p}{t}=p|\nabla u+ \theta \nabla v|^{p-2}(\nabla u+\theta\nabla v)\cdot \nabla v. $$

Comment: Thank you very much. Is a factor $(2\nabla u \nabla v + 2 t |\nabla v|^2)$ missing in the first line after "Noting that", and a $p/2$ in the second?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin, you are right. I made some changes.